# why we declare data binding adapters inside companion object?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I am currently learning Data Binding in android. But I did not find any answer to my question I mentioned above.

Also we annotate it with `@JvmStatic` but I don't know reason why we use this annotation?

```
class RecipesRowBinding {

    companion object {

        @BindingAdapter("onRecipeClickListener")
        @JvmStatic
        fun onRecipeClickListener(recipeRowLayout: ConstraintLayout, result: Result) {...}
    }
}
```

Also my another question is, is databinding a recommended standard? I read that data binding can make app build slower as it generates classes.

Comment: `do big companies use data binding in their apps` we can't answer that, we don't know what's a `big company` and what they are using, so i've edited that away to try and make it a question we can answer. secondly, android studio is just an IDE, so unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically, there's no need to use the tag :)